# Why doesn't XMLDocument.evaluate find nodes in this WMS GetCapabilities document

Tags: javascript, xml, xpath, wms

I'm trying to parse information from this [XML Document](https://geo.weather.gc.ca/geomet?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities).

The JavaScript below works for simple XML test docs but I cannot find XPath that will return any nodes from the real document.

he idea is just to list all the "Layer" nodes from the WMS GetCapabilities XMl Document.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,  Code below.

```
<html>
<body>
  <script>
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        parser = new DOMParser();
        xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xhttp.responseText, "text/xml");
        var iterator = xmlDoc.evaluate('Layer', xmlDoc.documentElement, null, XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null);
        var thisNode = iterator.iterateNext();
        while (thisNode) {
          documemnt.console.log(thisNode.textContent);
          thisNode = iterator.iterateNext();
        }
      }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "https://geo.weather.gc.ca/geomet?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities", true);
    xhttp.send();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to learn how to take a default namespace into account, using the third argument of the `evaluate` function to map a prefix you can choose freely to the namespace the elements like the `Layer` or `Title` elements are in and to use that prefix in your XPath expressions:

```js
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', 'https://geo.weather.gc.ca/geomet?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities');
req.onload = function() {
  var doc = this.responseXML;
  
  var namespaces = { wms: 'http://www.opengis.net/wms' };
  
  var result = doc.evaluate(
    '/wms:WMS_Capabilities/wms:Capability//wms:Layer/wms:Title', 
    doc, 
    function(prefix) { return namespaces[prefix]; }, 
    XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, 
    null);
  
  var ol = document.createElement('ol');
  
  for (var i = 0; i < result.snapshotLength; i++) {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.textContent = result.snapshotItem(i).textContent;
    ol.appendChild(li);
  }
  
  document.body.appendChild(ol);
  
};
req.send();
```

Comment: Genius,  works like a charm.This pointed me to some docs that explain that the default namespace is in fact a namespace... unlike the null namespace,

This paragraph in particular seems to spell out the semantics that was not clear on.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript